# .net service function param, cast custom object

Tags: .net, service

I I have service. I create a function where the parameter is not conventionnal.

the parameter is a List(Of KeyValuePair(Of MyObjectType, Integer))

but that made my function want an Array of KeyValuePairOfMyObjectTypeInt32.

Whats the best way to go with that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately generics are not SOAP friendly.

There are a number of limitations to consider.
Please see the section on Interfaces and Generics in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh273127%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#w) MSDN post.

Alternately please see the response to this thread:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5554873/1195927)

> Its turns out that the XML Serializer can serialize generic types of a sort. As neontapir correctly points out Generic types are not fully supported by the XML Serializer but it can still serialise generic types as it creates types of ItemResponseOfType[TheType] as I mentioned in my question.
>
> The XML Serializer just wont de serialize the type to a generic Type.

As far as an elegant solution is concerned, I don't really have one.  If anyone else wants to step in I'd be interested to know myself.

Personally, in rare cases (similar to what you described) I've used generics on the server side, and the client utilized the WSDL defined class (ie: GenericObjectTypeOfPersonTypeInt32)

Just to clarify (and reformat whats in the comments below), you can still call the following on the client side:

```
KeyValuePairOfMyObjectTypeInt32.Key
KeyValuePairOfMyObjectTypeInt32.Value
```

Comment: what you'll do if you want to give, to a service, a List(Of KeyValuePair(Of MyObjectType, Integer)) ?

Comment: On the server side you can specify that you want to give a list of KeyValuePair(Of MyObjectType, Integer).
The client, however, will see a list of that hybrid/non-generic object.  You can still use that "new" object.  ex: KeyValuePairOfMyObjectTypeInt32.Key
KeyValuePairOfMyObjectTypeInt32.Value
Sorry if I'm not being clear.  Can you elaborate on what is confusing you?

Comment: You are going to have to just create a class and pass that instead. So instead of List(Of KVP etc etc) you will want to create a class that explicitly has those properties you want. NewObject() { MyObjectType, Integer} and then pass a List(Of NewObject). There isn't much of a way of avoiding this.

Comment: I should have added the caveats. 
As @Dyslexicanaboko says: it may be cleaner to just define your own container class.  
This assumes your always working with the same key/value pair types every time.  If, on the other hand, you're utilizing multiple types requiring multiple container objects, then generics may still be the way to go.